# Qt Starting executable failed: [Path]:Success

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, qt5.4

I ran qmake and now every time I build, I get this message.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

it turns out there was a directory created with the same name as the binary being created in the build folder. just delete the directory